# Special Characters from SQLite DB

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I read from a sqlite db to my iphone app. Within the texts sometimes there are special characters like 'xf2' or 'xe0' as I can see in the debugger in the char* data type. When I try to transform the chars to an `NSString` Object by using `initWithUTF8String`, I get a nil back.

How can I transform such special characters?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like encoding issue. You can get 'xf2' or 'xe0' when you have such symbols as © or ®.  Those symbols need 2 bytes, and sqlite can interpret each byte of symbol as separate symbol.
So, try to use not initWithUTF8String, but initWithCString:

```
NSString *stringFromDB = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:charsArrayFromDB 
                                                  encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```